# MySQL query does not return proper results

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, request

Very simple question from a MySQL newbie :

I have a table with some information on transactions (amount_paid, date, product_type...). Each transaction has a unique ID, and I also have a list of transactions. I have to inspect based on this ID. So I'm doing a query like...

```
SELECT amount_paid, date, ID FROM transactions WHERE ID = 10 OR ID = 12 OR ID = 34 OR ID = 76
```

etc... (I've got something like 200 transactions to inspect)

What's weird is that in the result I have IDs that I didn't ask for, and I miss ID I asked for... For example, I query `ID = 435 OR ID = 439` and I got 435, **436** and 439 and on the contrary, I query `ID = 578 OR ID = 587 OR ID = 588` and I got only 578 and 588.

I still have most of what I'd queried, but with these strange discrepancies...

Following suggestions below, I tried to do the query with WHERE ID IN (435, 439...) but I got the same problematic results

If someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong, it would be great...

I'm doing my query from phpmyadmin.

Comment: are you missing `FROM table`?

Comment: Hi, no I'm not missing FROM, I just forgot to write in my question, sorry

Comment: maybe you're confused using `AND` or `OR` , if you're getting set of records you should use `AND` ant not `OR`. Please see answer below suggesting you to use `IN`

Answer (score 0):

As we know, the sql format for selecting data is `SELECT * FROM yourTable`. You miss `FROM` part

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, ..., idn)
```

Maybe you have a problem with the `OR`

Answer (score 0):

See query

```
SELECT amount_paid, date, ID WHERE ID = 10 OR ID = 12 OR ID = 34 OR ID = 76
```

you're forgetting `FROM table` should fix using this:

```
SELECT amount_paid, date, ID FROM mytable WHERE ID = 10 OR ID = 12 OR ID = 34 OR ID = 76
```

OR You can also try like this , something new for you

```
SELECT amount_paid, date, ID FROM mytable WHERE ID in (10,12,34,76)
```

Comment: Hello - thank you for the IN suggestion, but I have exactly the same problem when using this operator

Comment: @user2664793 , did you set primary key on your ID? can you post your finding like when you run the query show the results. Thanks!